# Collapsing child elements with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nlp

I would like to parse an HTML document and ignore span elements (but keep their contents) so that I can iterate the strings in the document the way a user would see them, as opposed to the way the HTML parser sees them. I've tried unwrapping and have not had the result I expected - here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
html = "<p>text <span>more text</span> additional text</p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for match in soup.findAll('span'):
    match.unwrap()
for string in soup.strings:
    print(string)
```

Intended result:

```
text more text additional text
```

The result I'm getting:

```
text
more text
additional text
```

How can I ignore the span tags so that when I iterate using html.strings the iterator will behave as though there were never any spans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different approaches:

**A: Join your `span` texts to a line:**

```
''.join([string for string in soup.strings])
```

**B: Just use `.text` on the `p` tag:**

```
for match in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(match.text)
```

**Examples:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = "<p>text <span>more text</span> additional text</p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for match in soup.findAll('span'):
    match.unwrap()
print(''.join([string for string in soup.strings]))
    
for match in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(match.text)
```

**Outputs**

```
text more text additional text
text more text additional text
```